# Automapper with nested destination Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to map a nested child property like so.

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Collection, CollectionDTO>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Items.Select(x => x.AddedToCollectionDate),
                               opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
                                   src.CollectionItems.Select(ci => ci.AddedToCollectionDate)));

});
```

`Collection.Items` is a `List<Item>`. Each `Item` has a `AddedToCollectionDate` property that I need to populate from the source mapping.

`CollectionDTO` has a navigational property to a cross-join table called `CollectionItem`, which has a property called `AddedToCollectionDate`.

**Error:**

> **Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.**

How can I achieve this with AutoMapper?

Clases (omitted other properties for brevity):

```
public partial class Collection
{   
    public virtual ICollection<CollectionItem> CollectionItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class CollectionItem
{
    public System.DateTime AddedToCollectionDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection Collection { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionDTO
{
    public List<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; }    
    public DateTime LastAccessedDate { get; set; }  
}

public class Item
{
    public DateTime LastAccessedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CollectionItem> CollectionItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Question: Are `CollectionItem` and `Items` the same type?

Comment: No. `Collection` table has a reference to `CollectionItem` (cross reference table) to an `Item`. `Collection` and `Item` has a many to many relationship.  I need the property `AddedToCollectionDate` from the `CollectionItem` table populated into my `Item` objects.

Comment: But are you  using in your DTO the same types of your data model or there are different?Please, add your classes to your question

Comment: `CollectionItems` and `Items` are different. I have added my classes to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by doing a `FirstOrDefault()` instead of a`Select()` selection like this.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Item, ItemDTO>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.AddedToCollectionDate,
                               opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
                                   src.CollectionItems.FirstOrDefault().AddedToCollectionDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `ForMember` call, you should configure a mapping for `CollectionItem` as well.

```
cfg.CreateMap<CollectionItem, ItemDTO>();
cfg.CreateMap<Collection, CollectionDTO>();
```

If you also rename `CollectionDTO.Items` to `CollectionDTO.CollectionItems` AutoMapper knows enough to map `Collection.CollectionItems` to the right collection in `CollectionDTO`.

Comment: Forgot one important detail.

Comment: Please refer: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html